# Using OAuth programatically to Login to other website

Tags: c#, oauth, console-application, google-oauth, bots

I want to write a bot, that begins to login with Google OAuth to a Website to get sessionkey and other cookies.
How can i transfer all the traffic through my program and read it. I am using C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WPF you can simple use an WPF WebView https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7

and if using Windows Forms take a loot at this example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-add-web-browser-capabilities-to-a-windows-forms-application

Indeed there are other ways to deal with Bots, I have done this before, the best approach would be using an google Chrome Extension Which would intact with your c# app through SignalR, It has a lot of learning curves but it works great.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lib `Google.Apis.Auth` u can read how to use it from  https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth